# É possível espelhar uma imagem horizontalmente (flip) com Canvas?

Tags: javascript, canvas, processamento-de-imagens

Sei que é possível espelhar horizontalmente uma `<img>` com CSS, mas
queria saber se é possível espelhar horizontalmente uma imagem dentro de um `canvas`.

Com CSS, eu faria assim:

```css
#img-flip{
   transform: scaleX(-1);
}
```

```html
    <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/pA0a1.png" id="img">
        <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/pA0a1.png" id="img-flip">
```

E com `canvas`? Como eu posso fazer isso?

```js
var onload = function() {
    var canvas = document.querySelector("#canvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var img = document.querySelector("#img");
    canvas.height = img.height;
    canvas.width = img.width;
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
}


img.completed ? onload() : img.addEventListener('load', onload);
```

```html
<div>Imagem original:</div>
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/pA0a1.png" id="img">

<div>Resultado Canvas:</div>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode utilizar o [`context.scale(-1, 1);`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2dcontext/#dom-context-2d-scale) e passar como parâmetro o `width` da imagem vezes `-1` ao realizar o `drawImage()` do contexto.

```js
var onload = function() {
    var canvas = document.querySelector("#canvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var img = document.querySelector("#img");
    canvas.height = img.height;
    canvas.width = img.width;
    ctx.scale(-1, 1);
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width*-1, img.height);
}


img.completed ? onload() : img.addEventListener('load', onload);
```

```html
<div>Imagem original:</div>
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/pA0a1.png" id="img">

<div>Resultado Canvas:</div>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Referência [HTML Canvas: How to draw a flipped/mirrored image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8168217/html-canvas-how-to-draw-a-flipped-mirrored-image)

Comment: Belo e moral. +1

Comment: @WallaceMaxters Obrigado! Estamos aqui pra isso! :)

Comment: Só pra constar `img.width*-1` seria o mesmo que fazer `-img.width`, ou seja a operação de multiplicação não é tão necessária neste uso.

Answer (score 2):

Recomendo usar o [`CanvasRenderingContext2D.translate()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/translate) junto com o [`CanvasRenderingContext2D.scale()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/scale), pois se usar apenas `CanvasRenderingContext2D.scale()` ele irá afetar o canvas todo, possivelmente deixando objetos fora do quadro (se a ideia for espelhar um canvas com mais de um elemento em diferentes posições), não sendo um espelhamento preciso, e isso lhe obrigaria a ficar ajustando `drawImage` por `drawImage` (supondo que vá usar mais de um) e outros elementos adicionados também que deveriam aparecer invertidos.

Exemplo do problema do scale negativo (note que o rect não esta na posição x=20):

```js
var onload = function() {
    var canvas = document.querySelector("#canvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var img = document.querySelector("#img");
    canvas.height = img.height;
    canvas.width = img.width;
    ctx.scale(-1, 1);
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width*-1, img.height);

    ctx.rect(20, 20, 100, 100);
    ctx.stroke();
}

img.completed ? onload() : img.addEventListener('load', onload);
```

```html
<div>Imagem original:</div>
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/pA0a1.png" id="img">

<div>Resultado Canvas:</div>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Então para "corrigir" isso, para que a posição x=20 no `rect` não fique invertida em relação ao tamanho do canvas (`<canvas width="...`) teríamos que compensar fazendo um calculo, exemplo:

```
ctx.rect(-(img.width - 100 - 20), 20, 100, 100);
```

Ou seja, temos que somar a largura do `rect` com a posição desejada e transformar o valor em negativo, exemplo:

```js
var onload = function() {
    var canvas = document.querySelector("#canvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var img = document.querySelector("#img");
    canvas.height = img.height;
    canvas.width = img.width;
    ctx.scale(-1, 1);

    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, -img.width, img.height);
    ctx.rect(-(img.width - 100 - 20), 20, 100, 100);
    ctx.strokeStyle = "red";
    ctx.stroke();
}

img.completed ? onload() : img.addEventListener('load', onload);
```

```html
<div>Imagem original:</div>
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/pA0a1.png" id="img">

<div>Resultado Canvas:</div>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

---

### Usando translate

No entanto ficar fazendo cálculos para cada situação pode ser custoso, até mesmo para o tempo de desenvolvimento, e com certeza você pode simplificar essa tarefa usando o `CanvasRenderingContext2D.translate()`, apenas assim `ctx.scale(-1, 1);`, para qualquer objeto. Se deseja espelhar na horizontal:

```
ctx.translate(-canvas.width, 0);
```

Se deseja espelhar na vertical:

```
ctx.translate(0, -canvas.height);
```

Exemplo de uso:

```js
var onload = function() {
    var canvas = document.querySelector("#canvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    var img = document.querySelector("#img");
    canvas.height = img.height;
    canvas.width = img.width;
    ctx.scale(-1, 1);
    ctx.translate(-canvas.width, 0);
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height);

    ctx.rect(20, 20, 100, 100);
    ctx.stroke();
}

img.completed ? onload() : img.addEventListener('load', onload);
```

```html
<div>Imagem original:</div>
<img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/pA0a1.png" id="img">

<div>Resultado Canvas:</div>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Pronto, desta forma não precisa ficar calculando nada, você pode aplicar mais de um objeto ou imagem ao canvas que ele vai desenhar como se fosse um espelho sem precisar de ajustes, o mesmo pode ser feito com o eixo `Y`, se deseja inverter na vertical ficaria assim:

```
ctx.scale(1, -1);
ctx.translate(0, -canvas.height);
ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0, img.width, img.height);
```

Answer (score -3):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>teste com canvas</title>
    
</head>
    
<body>

    <canvas id = "tela" width = "600" height = "500"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
<script>

var cnv = document.getElementById('tela');
var ctx = cnv.getContext('2d');

var flipY = 1;//mude o valor de 1 para -1 para virar o sprite em y//
var flipX = 1;//mude o valor de 1 para -1 para virar o sprite em x//

var nave = new Image();
var cores = new Image();

nave.src = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/VzSK8.png";
cores.src = "https://i.stack.imgur.com/ySTaH.png";
nave.addEventListener("load",draw);


function draw(){
    //56-Largura//
    ctx.save();
    ctx.scale(flipX,flipY);

    ctx.clearRect(0,0,cnv.width*flipX,cnv.height*flipY);
    ctx.drawImage(nave,0,0,200*flipX,200*flipY);
    ctx.restore();

    ctx.drawImage(cores,320,0,160,100,400,340,56,100);
    requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}
</script>
<style>
    #tela{
    border:1px solid black;
    position:absolute;
    left:340px;
    top:50px;
</style>
```

Comment: Testa esse codigo, a questão aqui é que usar scale altera o canvas inteiro se você não usar o ctx.save e ctx.restore. tem duas images em uma você  consegue virar a nave mudando os eixos, enquanto outra das cores não é virada no processo.